# Silverlight childwindow combobox lookup

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, combobox, wcf-ria-services

I am trying my hardest with silverlight but keep getting caught at hurdles for simple tasks.  I have a main datagrid on my main form that lists addresses.  I then have a child window that allows a user to edit these addresses with a combobox that does a country look up.  I have an AdreessDomainDataSource and a CountryDomainDataSource.
I have my combo box in my child window with code as follows:

```
         <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:Country, CreateList=true}" Height="0" Name="CountryDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetCountriesQuery" Width="0">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:CountriesContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>


    <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="False" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my:Address, CreateList=true}" Height="0" Name="AddressDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetAddressQuery" Width="0" LoadDelay="10000">
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:AddressContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
            <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="intAddressID" />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>



    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=AddressDomainDataSource, Path=Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,27,0,0" Name="Grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

This writes back correctly when i change to a different item in the list but on start up it is always replaced to the first item in the CountryDomainDataSource list.  I have put a breakpoint on my web.g.vb code and it appears that intCountryID is set correctly on start up but straight after returning it, it is getting overwritten by the first value in the list.  I have not written any code to set this value to the first value in my CountryDomainDataSource  list?  It appears that after the CountryDomainDataSource_LoadedData event is finished then it sets the countryid there.  Is there anyway to make my CountryDomainDatasource load first and then my AddressDomainDatasource second or am i doing something silly or wrong here as i have been scratching my head over this for awhile?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a DDS loads data successfully, it will select the first item in the list. For this reason (among others), I recommend you don't use it to populate ComboBoxes. Here are a couple posts put together by Jeff and me explaining the reasoning and better alternatives.

- [ComboBox Sample for RIA Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/18/combobox-sample-for-ria-services.aspx)
- [DomainDataSource, ComboBox, and Load Blocking](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/06/22/DomainDataSource-ComboBox.aspx)
- [ComboBox FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/11/02/silverlight-combobox-frequently-asked-questions.aspx)

Comment: I followed your suggestion and used your ComboBoxExtension although i seem to be running into some problems with possibly my Domaincontexts and the Async and AsyncEager mode.  If i run in AsyncEager i just get the single ID lookup value.  If i run in Async i get nothing.  So Im not sure if its to do with sharing the DomainContexts.  I set the DataContext of the Grid on the child window to equal the currently selected entity item in my parent windows datagrid on opening.

Comment: I then declare the CountryContext Lookup in the childwindow.Resources and then have the ComboBoxDataSource just above my combo.  Now you mentioned sharing the DomainContext.  How would i go about this?  Im a little confused.  Thanks again

Comment: On running this i put a breakpoint on my code and it does not seem to call my OperationName in my DomainService. Should this be running on startup of the form?  Thanks, Oly

Comment: The first link shows how to share a DomainContext instance. Typically, you create one instance in the page resources and pass it to all data sources. The third link goes into depth regarding problems you might see with 'Async' and 'AsyncEager' modes. Feel free to contact me from by blog if you have more questions.

Comment: After speaking to Kyle there were a few things to note. Firstly you should never use SelectedItem and SelectedValue binding at the same time.  Also another factor i would have never have got is you have to put the ComboBox.Mode at the end of the markup.  Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoLoad="False"` on AddressDomainDatasource to stop it auto-loading and trigger the `Load()` of AddressDomainDatasource from the CountryDomainDataSource_LoadedData event.

Or you could just set the [LoadDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.domaindatasource.loaddelay%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) of AddressDomainDatasource (might be a simpler option).

Comment: I have tried that and its still loading the address first.  Is it possibly because i bind the grid datacontext to the AddressDomainDataSource.  An example of my code is below:

Comment: Sorry i posted the code above as i couldnt fit it below.  Also the loadDelay does not appear to work.  Any other ideas?  Thanks for the help

Comment: I checked further and i found my eror was that i was loading somewhere else first so i followed your idea and triggered the load of the the AddressDomainDatasource from the CountryDomainDataSource_LoadedData which worked perfectly.  Cheers